# Replace data into string that starts with specific character and ends with specific character

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am currently working on an interface where the data is coming from a CSV and placed inside a div.

My problem is that the titles are merged with the text and I can't apply them a particular style:

```
<div class="projects">
*SEO* paragraph*SEA* paragraph*Design* paragraph*Data* paragraph
</div>
```

I'm looking for a Javascript solution that could append data to get this result and allow me to apply a style to the titles, the perfect result would be this:

```
<div class="projects">
<div class="title">SEO</div> paragraph
<div class="title">SEA</div> paragraph
<div class="title">Design</div> paragraph
<div class="title">Data*</div> paragraph
</div>
```

It doesn't seem like an advanced JS issue, but my knowledge is actually too weak to find the solution. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of problems the best way is to use regular expressions. They are not easy, but with a little experience and patience you can get there.

You don't need the characters "\r\n", are only useful to visually format the result.

[This is the Example with an online tools for regular expressions](https://regexr.com/5nvba)

**This is the working example.**

```js
var str = '<div class="projects"> *SEO* paragraph*SEA* paragraph*Design* paragraph*Data* paragraph </div>';


str = str.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '\r\n<div class="title">$1</div>');

document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.xmp {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<xmp id="code"></xmp>
```

The main line of code you need is this:

```
str = str.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<div class="title">$1</div>');
```